# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I want to click on the image and get textview text but im getting this error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

**XML**

```
          <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgClick"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Message"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="text yeah"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Here i want to acess to the above XML items!!

**Fragment**

```
 class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

 var newList: MutableList<News> = mutableListOf()

 companion object {
     fun newInstance() =HomeFragment()
}

private lateinit var viewModel: HomeViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)


    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)


    // TODO: Use the ViewModel

    val lastNewsObserver = Observer<List<News>>
    {
        // Access the RecyclerView Adapter and load the data into it
            newList -> recyclerView.adapter = NewsAdapter(newList,this.context!!)

    }

    viewModel.getNews().observe(this, lastNewsObserver)

    val img: ImageView = imageView.findViewById(R.id.imgClick)
    val msg: TextView = textView.findViewById(R.id.Message)
    img.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg.text)
        intent.type = "text/plain"

        startActivity(intent)
    }
}

 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

`imgClick` is `null`.  It's impossible to tell why without seeing the definition and initialization code, but if it's a normal variable, you need to initialize it after the view is created.  My guess would be that if you are initializing it via `findViewById`, you are doing so before `onCreateView`, at which point the view hasn't been created yet, so it returns `null`.

Comment: Im doing after as you can see on Fragment end of  file! How imgClick is null if when i write it it detect it and suggest the exact file i want to get it ... Not understanding

Comment: The code in your question does not initialize `imgClick` - please show the code that does

Comment: Im very begginer... I think im not initializing how should i do this?

Comment: Here's some information on how to declare and initialize variables: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/declaring-variables.html

Comment: val msg: TextView = textView.findViewById(R.id.Message)
        val img: ImageView = imageView.findViewById(R.id.imgClick)

        img.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg.text)
            intent.type = "text/plain"

            startActivity(intent)
        }

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.TextView.findViewById(int)' now gives this error

Comment: Okay, you really need to give the entire code (not as a comment, please) or I'm just guessing blindly...where are `textView` and `imageView` set up?

Comment: can you come discord i share my screen with you! This is  project for school and i really need to passs this error

Comment: Sorry, I'd rather not provide help outside of SO.

Comment: What entire code you need? from the xml file? I updated the fragment one